# Number of increasing functions from $\{1,2,\dots, n\}$ to itself.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

> Let $f$ be a function from $X=\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ to itself. We say $f$ is increasing if $a\le b$ then $f(a)\le f(b)$. How do we find the number of increasing functions?

I think if we can define $f(1)$ then we can count. But it is very difficult.

Comment: Is it the bijection function ?

Comment: If $f$ is bijective, then it is the identity, no?

Comment: @lulu that's right!

Comment: @Amir.no consider fix function.

Comment: try solve recursive

Comment: @Amir .yes I use this idea but I can't find recursive

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An increasing function $f$ is completely determined if for each $i$ we know how many $j$ there are such that $f(j)=i$. For any $i$, let  $a_i$ be the number of such $j$. We are counting the number of solutions of 
$$a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n=n\tag{1}$$ in non-negative integers.

For example let $n=6$. The solution $(0,1,0,0,2,3)$ of the equation $a_1+\cdots+a_6=6$ corresponds to the increasing function  $f$ such that $f(1)=2$, $f(2)=f(3)=5$ and $f(4)=f(5)=f(6)=6$.

By the usual [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) argument, the number of non-negative integer solutions of (1) is $\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$.

An equivalent way of putting it is that the number of increasing functions is the same as the number of $n$-element *multisets* that can be formed using objects chosen from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.

**Remark:** In a similar way, we can count the number of increasing functions from $\{1,2,\dots,m\}$ to $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.

Comment: An increasing function is completely determined by its multiset of values. For example, take $n=6$ and look at the function $f(1)=f(2)=3$, $f(3)=4$, $f(4)=f(5)=f(6)=5$. In my notation, this corresponds to $a_1=a_2=0$, $a_3=2$, $a_4=1$, $a_5=4$, $a_6=0$. I have written down a particular case of the natural bijection between increasing functions and solutions of $x_1+\cdots+x_n=n$.

Comment: Why your answer is correspondence by  answer of my question.let n=6 and 0+0+1+2+0+3=6 hence $ a_3 =1, a_4 = 2,a_6 =3 $ now how  define the increasing function? Increasing function is unique for this case?

Comment: For your $0+0+1+2+0+3$ we have $f(1)=3$, $f(2)=f(3)=4$, $f(4)=f(5)=f(6)=6$. Yes, the function uniquely determines the sequence of $a_i$, and any sequence (with sum $n$) gives a function.

Comment: By your definition of $a_i$ we can consider the decreasing function .this function is not unique.

Comment: Given any solution $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ of $a_1+\cdots+a_n=n$ there is a unique increasing function $f$ such that $a_i$ is the number of times $f$ takes on the value $i$. There is also, as I think you are pointing out, a unique such decreasing function. That just shows that the number of increasing functions is the same as the number of decreasing functions.

Comment: To use different language, there is a bijection between the increasing functions and the "multisets" of size $n$ we can form from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.