# Number of weakly increasing functions $g: \{1,2,3,....m\} \rightarrow \{1,2,3,....m\}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, monotone-functions

How to find the number of weakly increasing functions of $g: \{1,2,3,....m\} \rightarrow \{1,2,3,....m\}$? Here weakly increasing means that $x < y$ implies $g(x) \le g(y)$.

Attempt: The first element $1$ has $m$ choices(including $1$), second element has $m-1$ choices .....
So I get $m!$ , is this right?

Comment: $\binom{m+m-1}{m}=\binom{2m-1}{m}$

Comment: Could you elaborate? Looks like a composition formula of n into m parts.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1385227/number-of-increasing-functions-from-1-2-dots-n-to-itself?rq=1

Comment: How do you figure $m-1$ choices for the second element? The number of choices for the second element depends on what you do with the first element. If $g(1)=1$ there are $m$ choices for $g(2);$ if $g(1)=m$ thee is only $1$ choice for $g(2);$ only if $g(1)=2$ are there exactly $m-1$ choices for $g(2).$ Even without all that hard thinking, have you tried to check your answer $m!$ on some small example, like $m=2?$

Comment: if g(1) = 1 there are m-1 choices for g(2) {2,3,4...m}. Also if g(1) =2 then m-2 choices {3,....m}.Thanks @bof. Don't know what I was thinking.